# How to store the retuned values of a function into array in C

Tags: c, arrays

This loop simply passes every single character from `data []` to a function `cast` that converts characters to ascii.

My problem is that I want to store the returned values into an array 'buffer []', but it is storing only the first returned value. In other words, I want `buffer []` to has all the retuned values from the function.

```
for (int i =0 ; i < 8; i++)
{
    if (data [i] != '\0')
    {
        buffer [i] =cast(data[i]);   
    }
}

long cast (char b)
{
    long x = 0;
    x = (long)b;    
    return x;
}
```

Comment: You don't need a function just to cast a variable.

Comment: What is type of buffer? It seems like buffer is char and you just have undefined behavior.

Comment: @IvanIvanov long type

Comment: Maybe second character is 0. I just tested your code and it is fine.

Comment: @Abhishek the data type of data is char
buffer is long. that is why I'm using casting.

Comment: Oh, and how do you check that buffer is empty? If you print it with %s then it would be only 1 char long. First byte would be nonzero, and all others 0 (because they are empty, long > char)

Comment: @IvanIvanov are you getting values in the buffer array?

Comment: `long` is a signed integer type and higher rank than `char`, also an integer type. That assignment shouldn't need any casting *at all*, much less a function to do it. What problem are you **really** trying to solve. Are you trying to convert a character sequence of digits (ex: `"100"`) to their native `long` equivalence?

Comment: @IvanIvanov I'm printing it with %ld.

Comment: Still works fine. What about data, how do you fill it? Maybe, work with pointer, and there are some issues with allocating memory?

Comment: @IvanIvanov 'fgets(data,512,fl);' copies string from a file to data

Comment: my point of this is to convert string array into long array [2].

Answer (score 1):

No need to write a function just to do a typecast.

```
buffer[i] = (long)data[i];
```

Comment: Thanks. You helped me to remove the cast function.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by making the size of data array and buffer array the same.
Example;

```
data [512];
buffer [512];
```

so, now every element converted from data, are saved in buffer array.

Comment: posted as an answer as comments do not like formatting code.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition also has a fundamental flaw if it is dealing with strings.

```
for (int i =0 ; i < 8; i++)
{
    if (data [i] != '\0')
    {
        buffer [i] =cast(data[i]);   
    }
}
```

If data[3] == '\0' the loop continues until i < 8.
I suggest;

```
for (int i =0 ; i < 8; i++)
{
    if (data [i] == '\0')
    {
        break;  
    }
    buffer [i] =cast(data[i]); 
}
```

(was originally posted as a comment)